# Different ways of visualizing a certain classes of single variable complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, visualization

Single variable complex functions of a real variable are ubiquitous in engineering contexts such as control engineering and signal processing, and visualizing them is of utmost importance in designing systems such as filters. The functions that we encounter in control systems theory is usually of the following general form:
$$s=j\omega\,\,\,\,\,\,\,H(s)=e^{Ts}\frac{s^p+n_1s^{p-1}+n_2s^{p-2}+...+n_p}{d_1s^m+d_2s^{m-1}+...+d_m},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ p\leq m\,\,\,\,\,\,,\,\,\omega\in\Re$$

and in many cases $T=0$.

The most widely used  method for visualizing the above function  is [Bode plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot), that displays the phase and magnitude of it separately. I'm looking for other, possibly heuristic ways of visualizing functions with the above format. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

(I'm not sure, but maybe this question should be a community wiki question)

Comment: To properly visualize complex functions of one variable requires one to think of 4D graphs.  Since no-one I know is capable of doing this, I think it is easier if you simply realize that your intuition is likely to lead you astray.  However, one way to visualize aspects of a complex function is to draw the image of a circle or lines or other shapes in the complex plane.